# Проблема с подключением VirtualEnv

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, virtualenv, venv

linux_mint/python3.9

Такая проблема. Создаю virtualenv

```
python -m virtualenv env
```

Создалось. Запускаем, активируем, получается. Даже если теперь запустить

```
os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
```

То окажется, что переменная виртуального окружения создана, но если вывести

```
sys.executable
```

То окажется, что виртуальное окружение не активировано, а все библиотеки устанавливаются прямо на комп.

Как быть?

UPD1:
При использовании pipenv ошибка та же, но результат отличается в зависимости от использования. Например, script.py

```
import sys
print(sys.prefix)
```

Получаем вот так

```
(env2)$ pipenv run python script.py 
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment,
so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own
for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to
ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set IPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 
to suppress this warning.
/path/to/env2
(env2)$ python script.py
/usr
```

Даже сам pipenv говорит, что нет смысла запускать `pipenv run`, когда pipenv активирован, ведь, получается, что смысл есть...

UPD2:
Понял, что venv не то же, что virtualenv. При использовании venv возникла ошибка вроде `env/bin/python3.9', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip'`.

Comment: Можно чуть больше подробностей?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor использовал pipenv. Результат немного отличается, но в целом то же самое. Ошибка больше понятна через pipenv. Сейчас отредактирую

Comment: `но если вывести
sys.executable
То окажется, что виртуальное окружение не активировано, а все библиотеки устанавливаются прямо на комп.` - не окажется. Если под линукс работаете, то в виртуальное окружение не копируется интерпретатор python, а создается ссылка на него, при этом по факту при активированном окружении запускается системный интерпретатор (поэтому `sys.executable` покажет что-то вроде `/usr/bin/python3`), но с библиотеками из окружения.

Comment: @insolor так а как быть в итоге? везде и у всех, и в документации все работатет так, будто запускается виртуальное окружение и python оттуда, и библиотеки оттуда, а у меня все из реального окружения работается

Comment: У вас все нормально работает. Устанавливать библиотеки в окружение и не париться.

Comment: @insolor так дело в том, что они якобы уже установлены, хотя окружение только что установлено

Comment: Через virtualenv нужно создавать окружение с ключом `--no-site-packages`, чтобы глобальные пакеты не видны были. Если через venv создавать (это стандартное средство в отличие от virtualenv) это поведение по умолчанию.

Comment: @insolor разобрался. это достойно ответа. спасибо!

Comment: Посоветуйте, что лучше использовать: venv или pipenv?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124579/discussion-between-handowl-and-insolor).

Comment: pipenv никогда не использовал, обычно venv достаточно. Никаких проблем с ним никогда не возникало. Что лучше использовать - poetry)

Comment: @insolor спасибо, почитаю

Answer (score 0):

1. При использовании `virtualenv` желательно использовать флаг `--no-site-packages`, однако, у меня python говорит, что его нет. Говорят, что это дефолт и уже прописано в `.bashrc`. Проверять не стал, но `virtualenv` все равно подтягивает зависимости.
2. По работе получается

> venv != virtualenv

я для себя сделал вывод, что лучше использовать первый. Но с ним могут быть проблемы. Например, та, что в вопросе. Решается простой установкой библиотек
`apt install python3.x-dev python3.x-venv`

где вместо `x`, очевидно, своя версия.

Всем спасибо за помощь. Особенно @insolor